# Merging Geometry programmatically while keeping the individual positions of each shape?

Tags: c#, wpf, path, geometry

**What I have:**

If the user clicks and hold on a User Control, circle shapes are added. Imagine good old a paint.exe brush.

A thread is started, which is adding shapes at a rate of ~120 shapes a second. Performance is taking a big hit after about 300 shapes, so that's a max.

I want to combine all the shapes into 1 shape, every 5th shape added should combine all shapes into 1, or similar.

**What I have so far:**

```
List<Path> pathList = new List<Path>();

    public void PaintEllipse(Point pos, Size size)
    {
        double left = pos.X - (size.Width / 2);
        double top = pos.Y - (size.Height / 2);

        EllipseGeometry ellipseGeometry = new EllipseGeometry();
        ellipseGeometry.Center = new Point(size.Width / 2, size.Height / 2);
        ellipseGeometry.RadiusX = size.Width;
        ellipseGeometry.RadiusY = size.Height;

        var path = new Path();
        path.Margin = new Thickness(left, top, 0, 0);
        path.Data = ellipseGeometry;
        path.Fill = brush;


        var newShapes = GetShapesList(); // returns List<Shape> of pathList
        newShapes.Add(path);

        if(ShapesGUID == Guid.Empty) // updating the overlay 
            ShapesGUID = imageViewer.ShapesOverlayAdd(newShapes, new ShapesOverlayRenderParameters() { ZOrder = 100 });
        else
            imageViewer.ShapesOverlayUpdate(ShapesGUID, newShapes);

        pathList.Add(path);

        UpdateStatusString(); //updates a text shape with # of shapes
    }
```

Here's my merging method. The result is just 1 small circle left after running, possbily merging all shapes into the same location.

```
    public void MergeGeometry()
    {
        for (int i = pathList.Count-1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            if(i - 1 > 0)
            {
                var combined = new CombinedGeometry(GeometryCombineMode.Union, pathList[i].RenderedGeometry, pathList[i - 1].RenderedGeometry);
                pathList[i - 1] = new Path() { Data = combined };
                pathList.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }

        UpdateStatusString();
    }
```

So how am I to merge all Paths into 1 Shape/Path that keeps every individual shape's location/margin?

Comment: You know that there is an InkCanvas element? Besides that, 120 shapes per second seems far too much. How about 10 or 20? Or just add points to a Polyline with an appropriate StrokeThickness.

Comment: @Clemens I had no idea about that. I'll check it out.